# Where does R store packages?

Tags: r, package

The `install.packages()` function in R is the automatic unzipping utility that gets and install packages in R.

1. How do I find out what directory R has chosen to store packages?
2. How can I change the directory in which R stores and accesses packages?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The `install.packages` command looks through the `.libPaths()` variable. Here's what mine defaults to on OSX:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"
```

I don't install packages there by default, I prefer to have them installed in my home directory. In my .Rprofile, I have this line:

```
.libPaths( "/Users/tex/lib/R" )
```

This adds the directory `/Users/tex/lib/R` to the front of the `.libPaths()` variable.

Comment: this is what I'd like to do, but how do I access and .Rprofile? The prompt doesn't recognize it as either an object or a function

Comment: It is a _file_.  Again, read the fine manual, and/or help(Startup).

Comment: In Windows, I have:
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\R\win-library\3.5

Answer (score 67):

This is documented in the 'R Installation and Administration' manual that came with your installation.

On my Linux box:

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R>
```

meaning that the default path is the first of these. You can override that via an argument to both `install.packages()` (from inside R) or `R CMD INSTALL` (outside R).

You can also override by setting the R_LIBS_USER variable.

Comment: I've got a Windows Vista machine, but assuming the same procedure exists, do you specify the directory in the install.packages() argument list along with the package name?

Comment: Have you discovered 'help(install.packages)' yet?  Also, see 'help(Startup)' as per my last comment.  And do read those manuals.  Lastly, on *doze I tend to just set R_LIBS="C:/opt/R/library" in a file .Renviron. I know you are going to ask about that too -- so do read help(Startup). Ok? ;-)

Comment: I've got a dozen R manuals on my Kindle (including the 3,000+ page one) and wasn't aware of the Startup help file. I've been reading the manuals and hit a dead-end. Go figure it was a simple answer all along. Do I lose points for RTFM questions <- I don't have many to lose. 

Thanks again Dirk. See you at R/Finance next week. Ramping up on R skills as best I can so I don't get dusted during the presentations.

Comment: The 3000+ page is a collation of all the help page -- least helpful.  The aforemention 'Installation and Admin' one should be very useful for what you are after here.

Comment: is there an equivalent way to find these from the bash command line? i.e., an environment variable that specifies where the R libraries are installed if `$R_LIBS` and `$R_LIBS_USER` are not set? (I want to be able to execute an R script in the `inst/` directory of an installed package) on any Unix system.

Comment: Bubble the problem up: define R_LIBS / R_LIBS_USER somewhere else both your script and R can access -- maybe ~/.bashrc or /etc/environment.

Comment: I found out the hard way that the directory R_LIBS_USER must exist for it to be used.

Comment: great answer! just what I was looking for!

Comment: Also thirteen years old (!!) and unchanged (!!).  Sometimes that happens. R itself is a marvel of stability.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel do you mind commenting why `libPaths()` defaults to `[1] "/home/user-name-here/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"? 
"/usr/lib/R/library"` rather than `"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"`? Has there been a change to the default? Debian bullseye on my end. Could it be due to R installation at user rather than sys level?

Comment: @Johan you hit one of many answers I have given on this, maybe try the other ones, maybe come to the r-sig-debian list.  It has been hashed out a few times over the years.  In short, there is what I do _as defaults_ for the package but there is what you may do at your end.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel sorry, I'll search more throughly. Thanks for advice. apologies. See you on r-sig-debian.

Comment: No need for apologies but it is important topic and in the span of fourteen plus years it has comes up a few times.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks for the direction from the above two answerers. James Thompson's suggestion worked best for Windows users.

1. Go to where your R program is installed. This is referred to as `R_Home` in the literature. Once you find it, go to the /etc subdirectory.

   ```
   C:\R\R-2.10.1\etc
   ```
2. Select the file in this folder named Rprofile.site. I open it with VIM. You will find this is a bare-bones file with less than 20 lines of code. I inserted the following inside the code:

   ```
   # my custom library path
   .libPaths("C:/R/library")
   ```

   (The comment added to keep track of what I did to the file.)
3. In R, typing the `.libPaths()` function yields the first target at `C:/R/Library`

NOTE: there is likely more than one way to achieve this, but other methods I tried didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I copy pasted said line `.libPaths=("C:/R/library")` to my _Rprofile.site_ file.  I launch R 2.13.1 64 bit and get this error: _Error: cannot change value of locked binding for '.libPaths'_  I am using Windows 7.

Comment: See [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37883160/1811525): it should be `.libPaths("...")` (a call and not an assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You do not want the '='

Use `.libPaths("C:/R/library")` in you `Rprofile`.site file

And make sure you have correct " symbol (Shift-2)