# How to set the library location of installed R packages

Tags: r, package

My issue is that the package path I installed in R terminal is different from where I installed in R-studio.  So I'd like to change the install location. How can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages

Answer (score 0):

**R terminal:**

You can pass the `lib` argument to `install.packages` which specifies the library location.
See `?install.packages`:

```
 lib: character vector giving the library directories where to
      install the packages.  Recycled as needed.  If missing,
      defaults to the first element of ‘.libPaths()’.
```

**Rstudio:**

If you go to tools -> Install Packages, you can specify where to install your package in the dialog.