# Platform-independent way of locating personal R library/libraries

Tags: linux, r, macos, operating-system, package

### Actual question

How can I query the **default** location of a personal package library/libraries as described in the [R Installation and Adminstration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Managing-libraries) even after environment variables like `R_LIBS_USER` or `.libPaths()` etc. might already have been changed by the user?

I'd just like to understand how exactly R determines the default settings in a platform-independent way.

Naively, I was hoping for something equivalent to `R.home("library")`, e.g. `R.user("library")`

### Due dilligence

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages) and the answers sort contain the information/paths I'd like to retrieve. Unfortunately I only really know my way around on Windows, not on OS X or Linux. So I'm not sure if/how much of this is correct in a generic sense (home directory, separation of user vs. system-wide stuff etc.):

**OS X**

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library
```

**Linux**

```
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library
/usr/lib/R/site-library
/usr/lib/R/library
```

I also looked into the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Managing-libraries), but that only gave me a basic idea of how R handles these sort of things (maybe just looked in the wrong corner, any pointers greatly appreciated).

### Background

I sometimes create a temporary, fresh package library for the purpose of having a "sandbox" for systematic testing (e.g. when planning to upgrade certain package dependencies) .

When I'm done, I'd like to delete that library again while making absolutely sure that I don't accidentally delete one of the standard libraries (personal library/libraries and system-wide library).

I'm starting to put together a little package called [`libr`](https://github.com/Rappster/libr) for these purposes. Function [`deleteLibrary`](https://github.com/Rappster/libr/blob/release-0.1.1/R/deleteLibrary.r) contains my current approach (lines 76 ff.):

```
  ## Personal libs //
  r_vsn <- paste(R.version$major, gsub("\\..*", "", R.version$minor), sep = ".")
  if (.Platform$pkgType == "win.binary") {
    lib_p <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), "R/library", r_vsn)
  } else if (.Platform$OS.type == "mac.binary") {
    lib_p <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), "lib/R", r_vsn)
    ## Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages
    ## --> Hopefully results in something like: '/Users/{username}/lib/R/{version}'
  } else if (.Platform$OS.type == "source" && .Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
    lib_p <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), 
      c(
        "local/lib/R/site-library", 
        "lib/R/site-library",
        "lib/R/library"
      ), r_vsn)

    ## Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages
    ## --> Hopefully results in something like: 
    ##     '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/{version}'
    ##     '/usr/lib/R/site-library/{version}'
    ##     '/usr/lib/R/library/{version}'
  } else {
    stop("Don't know what to do for this OS type")
  }
```