# Issues with changing my default library path in R

Tags: r

I am having an issue changing my default library in R. I previously had a storage space problem on my university laptop and IT amended my user drives which left my previous Rlibrary in limbo somewhere on the previous drive. 
I have uninstalled and re-installed R a few times just to be sure, but it remembers my previous library location when I re-install it. And subsequently R struggles to see the packages I need to run my models.
I have subsequently tried (unsuccessfully) to implement the steps in this previous post: [Where does R store packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages) 
The main problem I encounter is when I attempt to edit the R.profile.site file using VIM it says E12: Rprofile.site: Can't open file for writing. I have also tried the same edit in Notepad ++ which doesn't work either. I am no computer programmer so perhaps there is a step I am missing here?

What I really want is one repository for my library. I would be happy to simply remove [1] below as this is the now defunct drive.
My current library paths are:

> .libPaths()
>   [1] "\\studenthome.qut.edu.au/group05$/n2559005/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"
>   [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"

Answer (score 1):

The issue your're running into is that windows has special permissions for subdirectories of `C:/Program Files/`.  You may be able to edit the site profile by opening it in R using the 'Open Script' option in the the File menu.

Incidentally, you can implement the same solution by creating a `.Rprofile` file here:

```
path.expand('~/.Rprofile')
```

and placing your call to `.libPaths( "/my/favorite/directory" )` in that file.  In addition, you can define a function like

```
.First <- function(){
    if( interactive() ){
        cat("\nWelcome",Sys.info()['login'],"at", date(), "\n")
        if('fortunes' %in% utils::installed.packages()[,1] )
            print(fortunes::fortune())
    }
}
```

in your `.Rprofile` file, and if you get your fortune at startup, you know that the correct file was sourced at startup.  See `?Startup` (specifically the third paragraph) for details.

Comment: I have run into the very issue you mention of not being able to edit the file either using VIM or R. So I tried the second solution, and it worked but only for my active R session, once R was shut-down and re-opened the problem persisted. Any further ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you the second solution didn't work, it's likely because `path.expand('~/.Rprofile')` is different for your subsequent R sessions, for some reason.   I recommend checking `path.expand('~/.Rprofile')` in the subsequent session, and checking that it points to the file you created.