# Where does R (for Windows) store packages before it installs them?

Tags: r, package

I am aware of where the installed packages go! ICMY, it's nicely outlined here:

[Where does R store packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages)

However, I do wonder where R caches the ZIP files (assuming Windows) it downloads from CRAN, i.e. prior to installing them in the library.

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: Run `install.packages` and find out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for `install.package` :

`destdir (parameter, default=NULL) : directory where downloaded packages are stored. If it is NULL (the default) a subdirectory downloaded_packages of the session temporary directory will be used (and the files will be deleted at the end of the session).`

The session's temp dir mentioned above is given by `tempdir()` command

Comment: Thanks, this helps indeed! Any hint on how to convert the tempdir() output to a copy/paste-able format without the double backslashes?

Comment: double backslashes.. i don't see them on  Linux  . you can use `gsub` to substitute anything funny. You can assign the value of tempdir to a variable and play with it. `tdir<-  tempdir()`