# Path given by tempdir() is not navigable

Tags: r, installation

Aren't paths given by tempdir() and path given after installing an R package supposed to be same?

I've read posts [Where R stores caches zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595090/where-does-r-for-windows-store-packages-before-it-installs-them)

but results of tempdir() on my computer gives a non existent path.

```html
> tempdir()
[1] "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSOm0pw"
```

and result of executing Install.packages("ks") is a path that I can navigate to and find zip files.

```html
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSOm0pw\downloaded_packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tempdir()` call gives you a path as a string, intended to be callable from inside R.

Since \ is the escape character for R strings but also the path separator in windows, you get duplicates of these that you should not have when you navigate to the file system in say, the windows file explorer.

If you want to see how the string is intended to look without the escape characters you can do:

```
cat(tempdir())
# C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSOm0pw
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. First time I looked at the paths, I thought they were actually different, but it is only double backspace. Thanks for additional info.