# How to tell R where to look for packages?

Tags: r, linux, package

I had my packages in the folder `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/`, which I moved and renamed without thinking. Now, I've restored the directory but R won't load packages unless I supply the argument `lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/`. How can I remind R to always look for packages there?

Comment: You should probably create (or edit) an `.Renviron` file in your home directory: see [here](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#renviron) for some help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right after I posted, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages) but I guess I'll leave it here for future reference. All you have to do is add the directory to the .libPaths variable with

```
.libPaths("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/")
```

Comment: See `help(Startup)`; this is but one of several wys to do it.