# Shiny package installation

Tags: r, shiny, installation, require

I tried to install shiny by using this command install.packages("shiny"), it works successfully, however, next when I tried to import it, I have this error "**no package names shiny is found**" and I don't know why, I tried to install by specifying the CRAN but it doesn't work
install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/').

Did any of you face this problem or can help me ? 
Thank you for your cooperation

[image]

Comment: this might be a local issue and not a problem with the repo. look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages), check which directory your packages install into with `.libPaths()`. after that you may want to install directly into one those directories like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I must add the **binary** type:

install.packages("shiny", type="binary")