# how to find the location of installed packages in RStudio

Tags: r

whenever I install a new package on my RStudio, a path is shown (which shows the location where the recent package has been stored). how can I use this path to find the exact location where the package has been stored on my laptop?

Comment: What do you mean "the exact location"? .libPaths shows where the packages are installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2615128/680068

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the path:

```
.libPaths()
```

Comment: I have already used this command but unfortunately, I cannot decipher the indicated data!

Comment: Note that **R** output the \ as /. So if you copy-paste the output, your system won't be able to reach the location

Comment: "C:\Users\T 3 N\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQfx7ei\downloaded_packages" => this is one of paths that is related to a package I have installed recently. how do I have to change this path to become readable for my system and where do I have to paste it to find the location?